# In AngularUI's nggrid, Edit On Focus Cell Selection Example does not .... edit on focus

Tags: angular-ui

Ng-grid has this example on its page,

titled : Edit On Focus Cell Selection Example

the pluker is : http://plnkr.co/edit/mfIWpK?p=preview

I don't see any editing being triggered.....

Answer (score 2):

The attribute has changed in the latest version 2.0.0.  It is now

```
enableCellEdit: true
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EzCZcM?p=preview